# Moving custom menuManager at the end of existing RCP app menu

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am working with an RCP application menu. As seen in the image below I am trying to move my newly added Help menu at the end of the freebies menus that come with my RCP application. Currently the code just adds it to the menubar by using a class that was created derived from ActionBarAdvisor .
        `public class ApplicationActionBarAdvisor extends ActionBarAdvisor`
Looking at the other methods available I see an appendToGroup method that might be interesting to use. Only thing is that it requires a groupName and I don't have one. The menu ids I have been using don't seem to suffice as a groupName.

[image: Where I want the menu to go]

Here is my code

```
@Override protected void fillMenuBar(IMenuManager menuBar)
{
    MenuManager helpMenu = new MenuManager("&Help", IWorkbenchActionConstants.M_HELP);
    //menuBar.appendToGroup(menuBar.getId(), helpMenu);
    menuBar.add(helpMenu);
    helpMenu.add(aboutAction);
}
```

[image]

Fixed it

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a custom menu programmatically is not the best way to go about this. Use the plugin.xml extensions tab to create menus then you can easily use the up and down buttons at the right of the text field with All Extensions to rearrange where you want each menu to be. So in this case, it's much easier to use the built-in Help menu of Eclipse. This whole action is resumed by adding the help menu right after the other menus in the plugin.xml file

````
    ``` <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
        locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu">
     <menu
           label="File">
        <command
              commandId="org.eclipse.ui.file.exit"
              label="Exit">
        </command>
        <command
              commandId="org.eclipse.ui.file.save"
              label="Save"
              style="push">
        </command>
     </menu>
     <menu
           label="Help">
        <command
              commandId="org.eclipse.ui.help.aboutAction"
              label="About">
        </command>
        <command
              commandId="org.eclipse.ui.help.helpSearch"
              label="Search">
        </command>
     </menu>
  </menuContribution>```
````

Final Result picture in question area :) I can't load it here

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding to an RCP which uses the normal Eclipse ActionBarAdvisor (`WindowActionBuilder`) then there is a group marker with id `IWorkbenchActionConstants.MB_ADDITIONS` positioned before the existing Window and Help menus.

There is an existing Help menu which has id `IWorkbenchActionConstants.M_HELP` so you can find this menu using:

```
IMenuManager helpMenu = menuBar.findMenuUsingPath(IWorkbenchActionConstants.M_HELP);
```

If you are writing your own action bar builder based on `ActionBarBuilder` then there are no groups defined in the menu manager and you can't use `appendToGroup`. You just call `add` in the order you want the menus to appear.

Comment: Did not understand the solution you are providing to me. I translate your comment as I should not use a MenuManager helpMenu? Instead change it to an IMenuManager and then add that to the group named IWorkbenchActionConstants.MB_ADDITIONS ?

Comment: I have given you two solutions, you can use either one. Either use the MB_ADDITIONS and your own menu or add to the existing Help menu.

Comment: okay then both options did not work for me (see photo in question above)

Comment: Well then are you using `WindowActionBuilder` or are you using your own class derived from `ActionBarAdvisor`? Update you question and tell us exactly how you are building the whole menu bar.

Comment: I am using my own class derived from ActionBarAdvisor although I can change it if it is preferrable this is my class "public class ApplicationActionBarAdvisor extends ActionBarAdvisor "

Comment: If you are just extending `ActionBarBuilder` there are no groups defined (unless you define them) and you just add the menus in the order you want them to appear - updated answer.